# full page iframe

Tags: html, iframe, footer

I need a page with a header and an iframe that show from other site.
here is what I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
    *{margin:0;padding:0} 
    html, body {height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden} 
    table {height:100%;width:100%;table-layout:static;border-collapse:collapse} 
    iframe {height:100%;width:100%} 
    .header2 {border-bottom:1px solid #000;height:90px;} 
    .content2 {height:100%} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="header2">
    asdasdasdasd
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="content2">
        <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

problem is that this code do not show footer complete (90 pixels is out of page because of header part).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tables are hurting my eyes. `position: absolute` is seriously underrated for this. Try this layout instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test Layout</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }
            #header
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; height: 90px; background: red;
            }
            #content
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 90px; background: blue; height: expression(document.body.clientHeight-90);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            Test content
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="startdoc.html" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Bonus points for rendering correctly all the way to IE6 and on every browser I've ever tested with minimal hacks :)

Comment: nice code but not working in old IE (IE7). need some code that support most of browsers.

Comment: I have no problem with this all the way back to IE6.

Comment: I will post complete example in a min, writing it up right now.

Comment: Okay, had to look back at one of our old project sources...fixed up now. I lied - there is an IE hack in there if you can spot it, but it is minimally invasive :)

Comment: You can, of course, just use a <frameset> as well. We used this because we wanted the entire page to be contained in one file so that we could manipulate the interactions between areas little better, and our layout had more areas (footer, side bar, etc).

Comment: thank you but not working in IE7 yet :( iframe do not cover page in IE7. other browsers are fine. and would like to use iframe and not frameset.

Comment: it is now working. body, html css settings was overrided with another css file. thanks :)

Comment: `display: table` is at least HTML5 compliant and not deprecated like this solution. Opt-in to the future with `<doctype html>`

Answer (score 0):

Make your header absolute positioned, so it overlays over the iframe, like so:

```
<table>
<tr style="position:absolute;top:5px">
    <td class="header2">
    asdasdasdasd
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="content2">
        <iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>​​​
```