# How do I use my HTML page inside my ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a .html.

I also have a .aspx that have two panels. I want to display my .html page between the panels, how can I do that?

I would like my .aspx page to end up with following structure. If I just drag the .html file in, it only creates a hyperlink. Should I put the .html code into a asp web forms instead?

```
...
<asp.Panel ...>
</asp.Panel>

.html

<asp.Panel ...>
</asp.Panel>
...
```

Comment: Refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973741/full-page-iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it in the same page, you could just paste the contents of the html body between your panels.

If your html is going to change in future, and you want it to remain a different page, use an `iframe` and set it to display your html page.

If you want to combine both on the fly, you can use a asp.net `Literal` control, read the contents of your html page and set the contents of the html to the `Text` property of Literal

Comment: I thought about a iframe, but should't I use an .ascx. What's it's called (webform? control?)

Comment: I don't see much merit to a UserControl(ascx) here. Those come handy for reusable code blocks, say a custom date picker which you want to use on many pages.

Comment: Ok. I heard they were used for reusable code blocks too. But I also thought they could be used for other purposes, like here to wrap the html. But it's maybe bad practice? btw, thx all for the answers, i think i have some good leads from here

Comment: Your aspx page is just as good to wrap the html. If its a logicall different block, you can sure put in in a UserControl, but remember that unlike a html page that can run independently, also be edited by a user who doesn't know asp.net; UserControls need an aspx page to contain them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iframe` to display html page.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="a.html" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your html page as user controls. Then include that user controls in aspx page. 
Details:
1. Create a user control. ( .ascs extention file ).
2. Place html code inside user control.
3. Create asp page.
4. Include user control in asp page via following code.

```
<%@ Register src="control.ascx" tagname="controlName" tagprefix="pre" %> 

 <pre:controlName ID="controlId" runat="server" />
```

Comment: He need the html page to display. Try to Understand the requirement first of all. Unwanted one to create the usercontrol. its take lots of  page loading time. html page decrease the weightage.